# how to play ustream's video on iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

i am new iphone developer, i want to play ustream's video on iphone sdk?
i have do so many try for do this but first of all i can't get the proper url of this video, here i have put this link of that video http://www.ustream.tv/chrispirillo  so please guide me how to paly this video to iphone sdk?

Comment: HLS url of 'chrispirillo' => http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/553/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8?appType=11&amp;appVersion=2

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They are using Shockwave player on the site and even if you get links (which is not that hard) all links points to files that are .flv files, so you would have to convert them before playing on iOS.

So the only solution that you have is to have some remote server on your own where you would convert and from which you would stream content to your iOS app, but those servers are not cheap because of bandwidth, cpu usage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mac Safari or other capable web browser.

Change user agent to the one used by iPad or iPhone Mobile Safari.
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3`

Then go to the ustream web site. By viewing source or inspection elements you can easily find *.m3u8 URLs. Those are URLs of the Apple HTTP Live Streaming contents and it is playable with standard AV playing methods.